# Pulling text from web.config

Tags: c#, html, web-config

I am wanting to pull text from web.config. I have added the following code
`<add key ="AssignedToText" value="Please submit a ticket to assign any users to this specific group."/>`to my web.config file. I want to display this text on the bottom of an ascx page. How can i go about doing so? How do code it into the ascx.cs file and how do I code it onto the ascx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ConfigurationManager to get keys from the web.config like this:

```
public string AssignedToText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssignedToText"];
```

Then in your .ascx page you can do this:

```
<%= AssignedToText %>
```

Comment: public string AssignedToText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssignedToText"]; do i add this to the Page_Load

Comment: Declare it at the class level by making it `public string ...` in your `.ascx.cs` file, then your `.ascx` page will be able to see it. Set the value in Page_Load if you want, doesn't matter, so long as variable is declared at class level of the user control

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much